# Problema com Extractall não extraindo exata ocorrência

Tags: python, ipython-notebook

Tenho o seguinte DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Texto' : ['é importante o sucesso', 'o dia está lindo']})
```

Tenho dois aquivos .txt nomeados *palavras_positivas.txt* e *palavras_neagtivas.txt*. Estes dois arqvivos são abertos e transformados em uma lista de strings da seguinte forma:

```
positive = pd.read_csv('palavras_positivas.txt', encoding='utf-8')
negative = pd.read_csv('palavras_negativas.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Os arquivos .txt são formados por uma unica coluna e cada linha tem uma palavra única. Ambos DataFrames são então transformados em string e usandos como em uma pesquisa:

```
lista_positiva = positive['Positivas'].to_list()
pattern_positivo = '|'.join(lista_positiva)
```

O mesmo processo é efeito para as palavras negativas.

Então uso o ***pattern_positivo*** e o ***pattern_negativo*** no seguinte código:

`df3['Positivos']=df3['Texto'].str.extractall(({pattern_positivo})").groupby(level=0).agg(','.joi`n)

```
df3['Negativos'] = df3['Texto'].str.extractall(f"({pattern_negtivo})").groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Meu problema é o seguinte:

no texto: ***" o sucesso é importante "***, eu consigo extrair as palavras "sucesso" e "importante" pois estão na lista positiva.  Na coluna negativa eu estou extraindo a palavra "impor" pois esta palavra existe na lista negativa, então por alguma razão o código lê "importante" e retorna "impor".

Meu Objetivo é extrair a ocorrência exata em ambos os extractall.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Boa noite! Poderia colocar na pergunta o formato dos seus txt?

Comment: Os txts sao palavras unicas  dispostas em uma única coluna.

Comment: Qual o delimitador?

Comment: Depois que transformo os txt's para string o delimitador é o pipe '|'.join(lista_positiva)

Comment: Tá usando regex? Qual?

Comment: No caso em questão ele tá retornando o que ele encontrou, não está explícito que deve retornar apenas se for uma palavra inteira igual.

Comment: Pois é. Preciso alterar o codigo para retornar a ocorrencia exata, comparando texto com a lista. Nisso que preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então o que tu quer é comparar as palavras, tenta assim:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Frases': ['Bom dia', 'Ok, vai lá', 'o sucesso é importante']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

negativ = ['mal', 'impor']
positiv = ['bom', 'ok', 'importante', 'sucesso']


def getByWordlist(row, wordlist):
    results = []
    for word in row['Frases'].split(' '):
        word = word.lower().replace(',', '')
        if word in wordlist:
            results.append(word)
    return results

df['Positivas'] = df.apply(getByWordlist, args=(positiv,), axis=1)
df['Negativas'] = df.apply(getByWordlist, args=(negativ,), axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
                   Frases              Positivas Negativas
0                 Bom dia                  [bom]        []
1              Ok, vai lá                   [ok]        []
2  o sucesso é importante  [sucesso, importante]        []
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!  Só preciso ajustar para não aparecer o [ ] no DataFrame, mas funcionou perfeitamente - Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Só faz um `return ','.join(results)` pra retornar string no getByWordlist